# When NSSecureTextField takes some inputs,, it randomly issues a warning

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

```
*** not expecting invalidation break on '_CFMachPortDeallocationFailure' to debug: {null - ic:0,ip:55311}
```

It is a normal NSSecureTextField, I am not doing anything special to it.When it becomes first responder and takes some inputs, it just issues this warning occasionally.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Note: Easy to reproduce (no code required) on Mojave when the text field becomes first responder or takes some inputs. High Sierra seems ok. It looks like a bug in Mojave to me.